# openCV_world452.dlll missing when running asciigenerator c++

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ascii, converters

So im am trying to convert an video to an ascii format to be able to run in a console with c++.
I found https://github.com/PtitGnou/AsciiVideoCPP , installed ffmpeg, python and downloaded the code from github.
When i run AsciiGenerator.exe i get the error opencv_world452d.dll was not found.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is something you have to solve.  Where is that file? Did you add the folder containing the opencv binaries to your PATH environment variable? Or did you copy these dlls to the same folder as your executable? This document from Microsoft explains how and where your OS will look for the required dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Answer (score 0):

So basically i followed this tutorial to install open cv:

http://%20https://sh-tsang.medium.com/tutorial-opencv-v4-2-0-installation-in-windows-10-eca7c2c8c300

But the first version i downloaded didn't have the dll i needed so i've downloaded version 4.5.4 , 4.5.2 and 3.4.15 ,extracted them in the same folder and it seems that one of them had my dll , now its working, thanks to everyone :)